# Mapreduce Custom Partition for NullWritable key type in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a requirement where i need only value from HBase not row-key to write into the output file .
For that i have used NullWritable.class as my map-output key type.
Now i have to partition my output data based on the columns value .But as we know custom partition works based on key and for that i am getting below exception.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Illegal partition for (null) (40)
```

This is where exactly i am getting exception in MapTask.class

```
 if (partition < 0 || partition >= partitions) {
          throw new IOException("Illegal partition for " + key + " (" +
              partition + ")");
        }
```

Here i how value of partitions is 1 and this is getting compared with my return int partition 40 and then it throws exception

Here is my driver code that i am using .

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(args[0], // input table
                scan, // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
                DefaultMapper.class, // mapper class
                NullWritable.class, // mapper output value
                Text.class, // mapper output key
                job);
```

This is my Partition code

```
public class FinancialLineItemPartioner extends Partitioner< NullWritable,Text> {
    public int getPartition(NullWritable key, Text value, int setNumRedTask) {
        String str = key.toString();
        if (str.contains("Japan|^|BUS")) {
            return 0;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|CAS")) {
            return 1;
        } else if (str.contains("Japan|^|CUS")) {
            return 2;
        }else {
            return 3;
         }
```

Please suggest ..

Note :If i interchange the map-output key/value parameter then my reducer is not working .

Comment: it does not make sense to have null key in mapper. how do you want to group your values in reducer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the VM .Same code worked fine in the cluster environment .